# Artemis cluster - load balancing with multiple acceptors

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, stomp, activemq-artemis

I have an Artemis cluster of 4 nodes (2 masters, 2 backups). Each one of the brokers has 2 acceptors - one for core protocol and one for stomp protocol (as stomp needs the prefix property). So they have different ports.

When I am connecting with the cluster from the Spring Boot app with jms-client 2.x and ConnectionFactory the addresses and messages are load balanced between the nodes. But when I try to interact with a stomp client it does not load balance at all. It seems that the cluster connections are not recognized somehow. I am not sure what the problem might be.

[The documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html) says that messages are load balanced over cluster connections:

> These cluster connections allow messages to flow between the nodes of the cluster to balance load.

So maybe I need some more cluster connections and connectors, which are configured in the `broker.xml`?

I have one STOMP client which connects to the first master node with port 61613. I can consume a message from the other node when I send it to the first master node, and I can see that the addresses are created on both nodes. One is like in a passive mode with a rack-wheel and one active with a folder symbol, which can be expanded. The addresses, which are created from the application are each just on one node.

The following shows snippets of the broker configs for one master and one backup broker:

master:

```xml
<connectors>
   <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
</connectors>

<acceptors>
   <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
   <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://localhost:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true;anycastPrefix=/queue/;multicastPrefix=/topic/</acceptor>
</acceptors>


<!-- failover config -->
<ha-policy>
   <replication>
      <master>
         <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
      </master>
   </replication>   
</ha-policy>

<broadcast-groups>
   <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
      <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
      <jgroups-file>test-jgroups-jdbc_ping.xml</jgroups-file>
      <jgroups-channel>active_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
      <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
   </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>

<discovery-groups>
   <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
      <jgroups-file>test-jgroups-jdbc_ping.xml</jgroups-file>
      <jgroups-channel>active_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
      <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
   </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>

<cluster-connections>
   <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
      <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
      <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
      <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>1</max-hops>
      <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
   </cluster-connection>       
</cluster-connections>
```

backup:

```xml
<connectors>
   <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
   <connector name="server1-netty-live-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>  
</connectors>

<acceptors>
   <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61617?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
   <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://localhost:61614?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true;anycastPrefix=/queue/;multicastPrefix=/topic/</acceptor>
</acceptors>

<cluster-user>user</cluster-user>
<cluster-password>pw</cluster-password>

<!-- failover config -->
<ha-policy>
   <replication>
      <slave>
         <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
      </slave>
   </replication>
</ha-policy>

<broadcast-groups>
   <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
      <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
      <jgroups-file>test-jgroups-jdbc_ping.xml</jgroups-file>
      <jgroups-channel>active_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
      <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
   </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>

<discovery-groups>
   <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
      <jgroups-file>test-jgroups-jdbc_ping.xml</jgroups-file>
      <jgroups-channel>active_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
      <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
   </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>

<cluster-connections>
   <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
      <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
      <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
      <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>1</max-hops>
      <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
   </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Thx @JustinBertram for your question. "It load balances well" means in my context, that the addresses and messages are load balanced between the nodes. With "maybe I need some more" I meant the cluster connections and connectors, which are configured in the broker.xml. As the connector refers to the port 61616 and the artemis-acceptor, which ist used by the app, too, I thought of adding some for the stomp-port/ stomp-acceptor. But so far those tryings did not work out.

Comment: I have one STOMP client, which connects to the first master node with port 61613. Now I tried your suggestion: I can consume a message from another node, when I send it to one node.

Comment: And I can see, that the addresses are created on both nodes. One is like in a passive mode with a rack-wheel and one active with a folder symbol, which can be expanded. The addresses, which are created from the application are each just on one node.

Comment: I updated your question to include this important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on all the information you've provided so far everything seems to be working fine. The documentation you cited says:

> These cluster connections allow messages to flow between the nodes of the cluster to balance load.

And when you send a STOMP message to one node you are able to consume it from the other which means that messages are flowing over the cluster connection between nodes on demand to balance load.

You don't need any additional cluster connections or connectors.

To be clear, each broker in the cluster will have its own set of addresses, queues, and messages depending on what the clients connected to them are doing. You shouldn't necessarily expect to see all the same addresses or queues on all the different nodes of the cluster - especially if you are relying on automatic creation of addresses and queues rather than pre-configuring them in `broker.xml`.

That said, you *will* see some different behaviors from applications using the JMS client (e.g. your Spring app) and applications using STOMP. This is because the STOMP protocol doesn't define anything related to advanced concepts like connection load balancing, failover, etc. STOMP is a very simple protocol and clients are usually quite simple as well. Furthermore, Spring applications typically create multiple connections. Those connections be balanced across the nodes in the cluster in a round-robin fashion which is almost certainly why those related addresses and queues appear on all the nodes and the ones for your single STOMP client do not. Client-side connection load-balancing is discussed further in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html#client-side-load-balancing).

*Messages* are distributed by the nodes themselves independent of the protocol used. That's the whole purpose of the cluster connections - to forward messages to other nodes.

Client *connections* can't be automatically distributed by the nodes themselves because that would require redirects and not all protocols (e.g. STOMP) support those semantics.

Comment: I see your point and what docu wants to say. Actually I was expecting a different behavior of the brokers, probably also because of starting with jms-client, which even spreads addresses. With docu saying **"If cluster connections are defined between nodes of a cluster, then Artemis will load balance messages arriving at a particular node from a client."** what I am actually expected was, that everything is distributed by the nodes themself (independent from the protocol used) and not only forwarded, like it is in this stomp-client-case.

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional details related to your comment. I hope that helps.